# Why is StateT faster in this example?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to benchmark performance differences of updating fields between non-monadic a -> a functions, StateT, and IORef. My benchmark code is below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Criterion.Main
import Data.IORef
import Data.List

newtype MyStateT s m a = MyStateT { unMyStateT :: StateT s m a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadState s)

runMyStateT = runStateT . unMyStateT

data Record = Record
    { ra :: Int
    , rb :: String
    , rc :: Int
    , rd :: Int
    } deriving (Show)

newRecord :: IO (IORef Record)
newRecord = newIORef Record
    { ra = 0
    , rb = "string"
    , rc = 20
    , rd = 30
    }

updateRecordPure :: Record -> Record
updateRecordPure !r = r { ra = ra r + 1 }

updateRecord :: IORef Record -> IO ()
updateRecord ref = do
    r <- readIORef ref
    writeIORef ref $ r { ra = ra r + 1 }

modifyRecord :: IORef Record -> IO ()
modifyRecord ref = modifyIORef' ref (\r -> r { ra = ra r + 1 })

updateRecordM :: (MonadState Record m) => m ()
updateRecordM = modify' $ \r -> r { ra = ra r + 1 }

numCycles :: [Int]
numCycles = [1..10000]

runUpdateRecordPure :: Record -> Record
runUpdateRecordPure rec = foldl' update rec numCycles
  where
    update !r _ = updateRecordPure r

runUpdateRecord :: IO ()
runUpdateRecord = do
    r <- newRecord
    mapM_ (\_ -> updateRecord r) numCycles

runModifyRecord :: IO ()
runModifyRecord = do
    r <- newRecord
    mapM_ (\_ -> modifyRecord r) numCycles

runModifyRecordStateM :: (MonadState Record m) => m ()
runModifyRecordStateM = mapM_ (const updateRecordM) numCycles

main = defaultMain
    [ bgroup "Pure"
        [ bench "update" $ whnf runUpdateRecordPure rec
        ]
    , bgroup "IORef record"
        [ bench "update" $ whnfIO runUpdateRecord
        , bench "modify" $ whnfIO runModifyRecord
        ]
    , bgroup "MyStateT"
        [ bench "modify" $ whnfIO (snd <$> runMyStateT runModifyRecordStateM rec)
        ]
    ]
  where
    rec = Record
        { ra = 0
        , rb = "string"
        , rc = 20
        , rd = 30
        }
```

The benchmark results are:

```
benchmarking Pure/update
time                 124.9 μs   (123.6 μs .. 126.2 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 124.5 μs   (123.0 μs .. 126.1 μs)
std dev              5.039 μs   (4.054 μs .. 6.350 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 40% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking IORef record/update
time                 70.14 μs   (69.48 μs .. 70.99 μs)
                     0.998 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 70.40 μs   (69.53 μs .. 71.51 μs)
std dev              3.141 μs   (2.634 μs .. 3.866 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 47% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking IORef record/modify
time                 131.9 μs   (130.1 μs .. 133.4 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 131.0 μs   (129.5 μs .. 132.8 μs)
std dev              5.712 μs   (4.667 μs .. 7.476 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 44% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking MyStateT/modify
time                 31.95 μs   (31.65 μs .. 32.28 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 32.06 μs   (31.72 μs .. 32.49 μs)
std dev              1.243 μs   (985.4 ns .. 1.564 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 44% (moderately inflated)
```

From the results it looks like the StateT version is almost four times faster than the non-monadic version and two times faster than the IORef version.

The code was compiled with -O2, -threaded, and -fno-full-laziness (the results didn't change much from adding -fno-full-laziness). I tried switching from `whnf`/`whnfIO` to `nf`/`nfIO` but the only thing that changed was the non-monadic version becoming even slower.

Can someone explain why the StateT version in this example is so much more performant than the other versions?

Comment: If you update the question but don't comment on an answer I have no way of knowing that the question has changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The benchmark is benchmarking a lot of things other than “how fast can you update a variable”. The main problem here is Haskell’s laziness. Something as simple as `updateRecordPure` does not quite behave as expected:

```
updateRecordPure :: Record -> Record
updateRecordPure !r = r { ra = ra r + 1 }
```

It forces `r` to weak head normal form, sure. But the `ra` field is *not* evaluated and we can prove this easily enough:

```
-- This just evaluates to (), it doesn't diverge.
updateRecordPure Record {} `seq` ()
```

So what is happening here is that `updateRecordPure` is creating a `Record` with a thunk in it. This problem in general (accumulating thunks) is a common problem with optimizing Haskell programs, and the other benchmarks suffer from this problem as well.

There is an easy experiment that we can run to see if something else is happening besides incrementing a variable. All of these updates should take constant time and constant space, unless they are accumulating thunks in memory. Try adjusting the 10000 to 100000… you will find that the runtime increases by more than 10x!

I have made a modified and cleaned-up version of the benchmark in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/depp/15514215cbd9f07eef319a0b1647d419) which takes as a command-line argument the number of iterations. It makes some other changes like eliminating the list and using `replicateM_`, which is a bit more idiomatic. On my system, going from 10000 to 100000 iterations has the following effects:

- Pure/update takes 80x as long,
- IORef record/update takes 30x as long,
- IORef record/modify takes 23x as long,
- MyStateT/identity takes 1x as long, and
- MyStateT/io takes 13x as long.

The `MyStateT/identity` benchmark is just `MyStateT` applied to the `Identity` monad. Somehow, GHC is able to completely optimize this case away and the runtime for this case is 14 ns... no matter how many iterations you use!

But for the others, because increasing the number of iterations 10x increased the runtime by more than 10x, we know that something is going on here other than just incrementing an integer and allocating a record.

### Fixing the Benchmark

The lazy way to fix the benchmark is to make the record field strict.

```
data Record = Record
    { ra :: !Int
    , rb :: String
    , rc :: Int
    , rd :: Int
    } deriving (Show)
```

With this change, going from 10000 to 100000 iterations increases the runtime by about 10x for Pure/update, IORef record/modify, and MyStateT/io. IORef record/update is still slow as expected because it is constructing a chain of 10000 or 100000 chunks on the heap and then evaluating them at the end (this behavior is well known and documented in the `modifyIORef` documentation, although it still catches many Haskell programmers by surprise).

On my anemic VPS, the new version with strict `ra` field has the following times with 10000 iterations, ranked from fastest to slowest:

1. MyStateT/identity: 13.67 ns
2. Pure/update: 72.72 μs
3. IORef record/modify: 664.2 μs
4. MyStateT/io: 1.170 ms
5. IORef record/update: 16.84 ms

With these changes, the `MyStateT/identity` benchmark still somehow triggers some GHC optimization which eliminates the loop. From the other implementations, the pure one is the fastest, which is expected, and adding additional complications (using an IORef, then using IO + StateT) make the benchmark slower. Finally, `readIORef` + `writeIORef` is the slowest because it creates a large number of thunks.

Note that the pure implementation takes only 7 ns per iteration.

Compiling without `-threads` drastically reduces the runtime, bringing Pure/update, IORef record/modify, and MyStateT/io within 25% of each other. So we can conclude that the differences are due to some kind of synchronization necessary for using IO in multithreaded programs, or perhaps a difference in code generation for multithreaded programs that prevents certain types of optimizations from optimizing our benchmark.

Comment: The OP has updated their question to use `Control.Monad.State.Strict`, but the results are still similar.